# how to comment in sublime if the multiple lines already contain comments?

Tags: html

I have this problem that I want to comment a whole section of code in HTML, this section of code already have some comments inside. now if I want to comment the whole section, how can I do it. the ctrl + / dont work anymore.....

```
<div class="meta">
    <hr>
    <!-- some comments -->
    <span class="meta_date"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> <strong>Date:</strong> 
    <a href="#">2016.05 - 2016.06</a></span>
    <!-- some comments -->
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
<?/* html code */?>
```

Or

```
<script>/* html code */</script>
```

Comment: thanks, <script> can work! but the first one can not

Comment: The first one can work if you use php ;) u can start with <?php  ?>